# Show hyperlink only for smartphone users?

Tags: html, css

I want to show a hyperlink only for phone users and not desktop users. Is this the way to do it?

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) 
{
    <a href="xxxxx"> Test <\a>
}
```

Comment: No, you don't put HTML in a media query - you put CSS inside the media query, which targets your HTML using a selector. You seem to be a bit mixed up here, maybe a little more reading on the topic is required?

Comment: surround you hyperlink with a div and add a class to it, e.g. class="shownoshow". in your media query add .shownoshow{ display: block; }. in the main css add .shownoshow{ display: none; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You don't want to add HTML to the CSS, it won't work.

The HTML:
`<a class="formobile" href="0000000"> Phone # </a>`

The CSS:

```
a.formobile { display: none; }
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) { 
a.formobile { display: block; /* or display: inline-block; or display: inline; depending upon surrounding markup */ }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the link in your HTML page
2. Target it with *device* width specifically to show on those resolutions and mobile devices.

Note that I used [`min-device-width` as opposed to `min-width`.](https://www.sitepoint.com/media-queries-width-vs-device-width/) Use what is suitable for your project.

Something like this

```
a.mobile-only {display: none;}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 480px) {
    a.mobile-only {display: inline;}
}
```